# How can I push ItemName to my database(SQL) from Select2() dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-core, jquery-select2

i am new on asp.net razor page

this is my Html

```html
<div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <select class="form-control" id="itemslist" name="itemName" asp-items="Model.Itemslist">
                        <option value="SSS"></option>
                    </select>
                    <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="itemName"asp-for="Expiree.ItemName"  />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    @if (ViewData["Message"] != null)
                    {
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            window.onload = function ()
                            {
                          alert("@ViewData["Message"]");
                             };
                        </script>
                    }
                </div>
```

this my script section

```
@section scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#itemslist").select2();
        });
        $("body").on("change", "#itemslist", function () {
            $("input[name=itemName]").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
        });
    </script>

}
```

this my page model

```
namespace SparkAuto.Pages.Expire
{
    public class CreateeModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public CreateeModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        public SelectList Itemslist { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public Expiree Expiree { get; set; }
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            this.Itemslist = new SelectList(_db.Items, "Id", "Name");


            return Page();
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
           
            _db.Expiree.Add(Expiree);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

finally this my error i get Null in itemName in database

[image]

this a screenshot from searchable select2 dropdown list i use

[image]

I search in 3K items in this dropdown list and need to push the item name after selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use select to bind id of `Expiree`,and bind `ItemName` with hidden input:

Expire:

```
public class Expiree {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
    }
```

html:

```
<select class="form-control" id="itemslist" asp-for="Expiree.ItemId" asp-items="Model.Itemslist">
        <option value="SSS"></option>
    </select>
    <input class="form-control" type="hidden" asp-for="Expiree.ItemName" />
```

js:

```
@section scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#itemslist").select2();
        });
        $("body").on("change", "#itemslist", function () {
            $("#Expiree_ItemName").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
        });
    </script>

}
```

Comment: Can you accept it as an answer?Thank you.